# Manage multiple python versions on both architectures with M1 mac

Tags: python, homebrew, pyenv, apple-m1, apple-silicon

Is it possible to have 2 different versions of python with different architecture on M1 macbook with tools like `pyenv`?

For instance, I would like to have `3.9.1` on ARM and `3.8.5` on x86 (via rosetta).

I have `pyenv` installed already with a new `homebrew 3.0.0`. Having that, I am able to install 3.9.1 for ARM (`pyenv install 3.9.1`). Can I now have another version which would be through rosetta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://sixty-north.com/blog/pyenv-apple-silicon.html) is a solution that does just that. I hope it's still useful.

Quick summary:

1. Make sure Rosetta 2 is installed (it translates software designed for x86 to something ARM can digest)
2. Install a x86 and a ARM version of homebrew
3. Install a x86 and a ARM version of the packages required by pyenv.
4. Install pyenv
5. Use aliases to refer to a x86 and an ARM version of pyenv
6. Use pyenv-alias to install and refer to x86 and/or ARM python versions.